# Installing afpfs-ng from source

Tags: debian, osx, file-sharing

I want to install afpfs-ng to get access to an AFP share from my Mac. I am running Debian and  am following instructions from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/175/17242, and I get

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... no
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details.
```

Does it mean there were some issues during installation? Are there any better ways of enabling AFP access on Linux?

Comment: Your question is not quite clear: do you want to compile `afpfs-ng` on a Mac or on Debian? (I assume it's the second). Please edit it.

Comment: I am compiling on debian, edited my question, I hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 3):

On Debian there's a meta-package that contains most programs you'll need to do compilations.

```
apt-get build-essential
```

You'll also want to get the build dependancies required by `afpfs-ng`:

```
apt-get install libgcrypt-dev libfuse-dev libgmp-dev libreadline-dev libncurses-dev
```

(That list was obtained from http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/afpfs-ng/afpfs-ng_0.8.1-5.dsc)

Answer (score 1):

> configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH

You need to install the C compiler. Try `apt-get install gcc`.

Comment: Ok, done it, when trying to compile now I get the following error

configure: error: FUSE is not installed.  To build without fuse, configure with '--disable-fuse'

Comment: You need to install the fuse-related packages. (don't have a Debian here, but try searching with `apt-cache search fuse`).

Comment: I get a huge list of packages [here](http://imgur.com/Y6K37,BL6C3), should I install one of these?

Comment: Try installing `libfuse-dev`.

Comment: Installed libfuse-dev, trying to compile again, getting [this](http://imgur.com/8Zmy9,dj3VF,SUsyg,QFiFf)

Comment: try `libreadline-dev`.

Comment: Still, [no luck](http://pastebin.com/vNyJsv7i)

Comment: Why would you say it isn't working?  Looks like it installed just fine.  Note:  everything is installed in /usr/local directories.  I suspect any of the binaries linked against /usr/local/lib/libafpclient.so.0.0.0 will require an LD_LIBRARY_PATH set or to put it in your ld.conf.