# Different ways to download and install an application in Fedora

Tags: fedora, package-management

I want to know what are the different ways to install an application in Fedora based systems. One is downloading a `.rpm` package of the application from its site and double clicking will install it.

I am using Fedora 34 and would like to know the other ways to download/install packages, in particular those using the terminal.

Comment: You really want to know the **best** or most reliable way. RPM's are longstanding, but it seems fashionable for every distro to invent a totally different way. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all distributions your preferred method of installing applications should always be from the distribution [repositories](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/repositories/). So for Fedora this means using [DNF](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/dnf/) from the terminal or a graphical tool from your desktop environment (e.g. [GNOME Software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Software) for GNOME). If something is not available in the Fedora repositories, you should try to find and add a [third party repository](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Workstation/Third_Party_Software_Repositories) to your system. [RPMFusion](https://rpmfusion.org/) is a popular one because it includes some software that Fedora can't ship due to licensing issues.

Some applications are also available as [flatpaks](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/flatpak/), this includes some popular proprietary applications like Steam, Spotify or VS Code. GNOME Software also allows you to install and manage Flatpak applications or you can use the [`flatpak`](https://developer.fedoraproject.org/deployment/flatpak/flatpak-usage.html) command from the command line.

Manually downloading and installing RPMs should be your last option -- when installing from a repository (or with flatpaks) your applications will be updated when a new version is pushed to the repository, you don't need to actively check the website for a new package to download (you still need to actively start the update using DNF/flatpak, but it's one "action" for all your applications).

And you can also [compile the application from source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/173/how-to-compile-and-install-programs-from-source) but you should be able to avoid this and install everything you need from repositories.

Comment: Want to install vscode using DNF but there are different ways given in different sites. How to know the package-name of the application like for vscode.

Comment: If you don't know the exact name, you can always use `dnf search` first. Steps for vscode installation on Fedora (including adding the Microsoft repository) are available [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux#_rhel-fedora-and-centos-based-distributions).

Comment: And by using .rpm package of any application we can just install the app by double clicking the package. Is there any other way to use this package to install the app?

Comment: @Shawn These are the [install instructions for Fedora from `code.visualstudio.com`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux#_rhel-fedora-and-centos-based-distributions) that I used and worked fine.

Comment: @rickhg12hs Yes I did this. It's working. Just want to know Is there any other use of **.rpm file** to install an app? Like one use of it is that we can double click it to install the app.